# python3: How can I run a python script when python starts?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a shortcut which runs `python3` in a terminal window. I would like to add some import commands to a python script which is to be run when python starts.

How can I do this?

eg; I have `xfce4-terminal -e python3` which starts a graphical terminal session with python3 running. I want to add something to this to make python3 execute a script, however I do not want python to exit at the end of the script, which is the default behaviour if a filename is given immediatly following the `python3` command.

Comment: `python3 -i filename`?

Comment: Yep that's it thanks. I read the man page but didn't realize this was what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

See `python --help`. It mentions an environment variable called `PYTHONSTARTUP` which looks like it could help you get where you want.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought of. Here's a narrative walkthrough from google: https://www.tommygeorge.com/blog/pythonrc-files-and-python-startup/